# How to reset CCSM opacity back to 100%?

Tags: 11.10, compiz

By mistake i set CCSM's opacity to 0 so when I run it it looks as if it wasn't open. How to reset it to 100% opaque without resetting compiz???

Comment: strangely, the default opacity is 0, it should be 100, all windows vanished here just after I pressed tab after typing "any" on windows match field...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `gedit ~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1/plugins/obs/screen0/options/%gconf.xml` and you should see something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
        <entry name="opacity_values" mtime="1332424921" type="list" ltype="int">
                <li type="int" value="0"/>
                <li type="int" value="0"/>
        </entry>
        <entry name="opacity_matches" mtime="1332424762" type="list" ltype="string">
                <li type="string">
                        <stringvalue>class=Ccsm</stringvalue>
                </li>
        </entry>
</gconf>
```

Note the first `<li>` in `<entry name="opacity_values" ..>` so that it reads `<li type="int" value="100"/>`.  Save, log out and back in and it should be fixed.

---

Or you can disable the opacity plugin with one (long) command:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=list --list-type=string /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins "$(gconftool-2 --get  /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins | sed 's/obs,?//')"
```

That will need you to log out and in again still.

---

Edit (this won't work for fixed-opacity windows): The default binding for increasing opacity is <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>MousewheelUp</kbd> so you could guess where the window is and try that.

Comment: "The default binding for increasing opacity is Alt-MousewheelUp so you could guess where the window is and try that" - easiest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Configuration parameters for the CCSM are stored within the `~/.config/compiz/compizconfig`. It's a text file that you can edit to see if there is a 0 value for opacity and change it to 100.

Comment: Unfortunately that only stores information about CompizConfig, not the Compiz settings.

Comment: Agree, the question is about CCSM opacity